# Timebound access to system

Tags: java, oracle10g, jboss7.x

Actually I have got a  situation ,and I am looking for guidance ..
The thing is I have got a table which contains entries for days and time at which a  user can access the system .

The columns are in this way :-

Userid
day
accesstimefrom
accesstimeto

now I am looking for a way by which I can ensure that for a particular user who has got entry in the table ,the user should be able to access the system at the time and day specified in the table upto the value in accesstimeto column of my table .for if

```
userid =1
day=wednesday
accesstimefrom=02:00
accesstimeto=04:00
```

then user with userid =1 can access the system only at wednesday at 02:00 in the night till 04:00 i.e for 2 hrs

Please provide a way how can I achieve this ,

```
I am using 
Jboss 7.1 as server
oracle 10g  DB
Java
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: also include the proper imports,

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
```

to get the current time and date, you'll probably want to use something like

```
timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEYYYYMMddHHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

E is the the day of the week (Mon, Tue, Wed, etc), YYYY is year, MM is month, dd is day of month, HH is hour, mm is minute, ss is second. Then parse it out into ints if you need to, like

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(timeStamp.substring(0, 4));
```

After that, it's a simple matter to compare the access time to the the values found by the above code when the user tries to access

To measure time that has passed, have your program know when the program started

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and then check repeatedly with a loop to see how much time has passed and

```
if(it's been too long) {kick them out}
```

So if the user accesses your program at 4:27:00 and needs to be kicked out at 4:28:30...

```
long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
if(estimatedTime / 1000 > 90) //estimatedTime is in milliseconds, divide by 1000 to get seconds
    thisMethodKicksTheUserOut();
```

Keep in mind that there are a lot of ways you could implement your program, and this is my quick-and-dirty take on it. There are plenty of resources on getting/measuring time in Java on the internet, perhaps you should peruse some of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,but I have got one question what about the auto exit from the system ,when that assigned time is over ,how will I keep track of duration

Comment: There are a variety of ways; I would probably do it by checking the time every minute or so and seeing if it's past the right time. I'll append something to my answer in a second

Comment: Thanks kevin for this approach , will let you know ,,, if I will face any problem .Kudos for this

Comment: No problem, here's a good resource in case you run into trouble - as a bonus, I discovered how to get the day of the week from the date! Edited my answer to reflect that.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm

Comment: but I was wondering isnt there a way ,where I can firstly fetch the corresponding day stored in my table for that particular user ,,,and after that get the current day not date and match them both...time is not an issue but I was wondering about day

Comment: Updated the day of the week part of my answer. If you want the full string of the day (i.e. "Saturday" instead of "Sat") put EEEE instead of EEE. You can then use that for a string comparison